# React onClick property not present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, onclick

I'm running into a hiccup with react. I've used it before and just can't figure out whats wrong this time. I'm tyring to put an onClick listener on an anchor but its not working. To be more percise, the event listener isn't being bundled at all. When I use the react dev tools on the element it doesn't register that their is an event listener at all, much less a desired function to be fired. Any ideas why?

Here code:

```
import React from 'react';


class OpeningDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this)
    }

    onClickHandler(){
        console.log("hey")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="opening-display">
                <div id="options">
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="webpages-option" onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Webpages
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="codepens-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Codepens
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OpeningDisplay;
```

I'm using webpack to bundle the code so here's my config file (if necessary):

```
const path = require('path')


module.exports = {
    // webpack folder's entry js -excluded from jekyll's build process
      entry: './webpack/entry.js',
      output: {
        //put the generated file in the assets folder so jekyll will grab it
        path: path.resolve('src', './portassets'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
            use: [
              {
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "[name].[ext]",
                    publicPath: '/',
                    outputPath: 'portassets/images/'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

If any other info is needed just ask.

So I'm new to the react devtools but from what I've seen, when an element is selected all the properties are shown including listeners like "onClick" etc. But my onClick isn't being shown. Any idea what's up?

**Edit**
So I pushed the repository up to github and the "onCLick={blahblah}" doesn't get pushed up to the repository. Could it be my text editor? Or some other mysterious thing?

**Edit 2**
So I checked my git repository and it looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';


class OpeningDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="opening-display">
                <div id="options">
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="webpages-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Webpages
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="codepens-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Codepens
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OpeningDisplay;
```

I made a slight change to the and git tracked the change and let me make another commit. But the change still didn't show up in the remote repository...

Comment: When you click the link, do you get any type of error or warning? Did you try restarting your bundle process?

Comment: I don't get any error or warning. I've ran the bundle with the onClick expression being something as simple as a console.log("clicked"). No matter what happens it seems like the onClick just isn't registered in the bundle...

Comment: Here's your component code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/85221/. When isolated, it works as expected. So the problem seems to be in Webpack. In the output bundle file, do you see your click handler function?

Comment: I just changed this in the edit, but I pushed the changes up to github and the onClick={blahblah} doen't even appear in the remote repository. Any idea what this says about the problem?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you're checking the correct remote branch?

Comment: yeah def sure. I asked another question detailing the problem with github [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015521/git-remote-repository-doesnt-match-local-even-after-push)

Comment: found the stupid answer. Moved the file to a different location, but file was still open in text editor. So all the changes and saves I made created a new file in the old location and weren't referenced correctly. I'm dumb

Comment: It happens. Probably you were tired so you over-coded this one :). But it's great it works now!