# Git remote repository doesn't match local (even after push)

Tags: git, github

My git repository and local branch are different even after push. Consecutive pushes just returns "Everything up-to-date". The really weird thing is that I'm using webpack to bundle the files and webpack doesn't sense the local file differences either. It bundles the files as they look in the repository (which is causeing problems like the onClick function not firing or being noticed at all). Does anybody know why this would happen?

Here is the code:

local file:

```
import React from 'react';


class OpeningDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this)
    }

    onClickHandler(){
        console.log("heyyy")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="opening-display">
                <div id="options">
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="webpages-option" onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Webpages
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="codepens-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Codepens
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OpeningDisplay;
```

remote git file:

```
import React from 'react';


class OpeningDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="opening-display">
                <div id="options">
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="webpages-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Webpages
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href='#' className="row" id="codepens-option">
                        <div className="option col text-center btn-lg">
                            Codepens
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OpeningDisplay;
```

futher info:
when I make a change to the parts of the file that are not being pushed remotely, like changing:

```
onClickHandler(){
        console.log("heyyy")
}
```

to:

```
onClickHandler(){
        console.log("heyyyyyy")
}
```

and make an add and commit, the commit is tracked. And when I push the changes it doesn't return "Everything up-to-date" so I believe changes are being tracked in some fashion...

Comment: it seems you have problem with your git config or something else. git doesn't change anything on your source files.

Comment: the source file is fine and showing exactly what I want it to show. Its the remote file on github that is unchanged even though it should change after a push.

Comment: check your browsers cache etc. git doesn't change anything ever.

Comment: Are you sure you made a commit  with your local modifications? (check `git status` for instance). Also, which command do you use to push? And on which branch do you push?

Comment: Absolutley sure, (made other changes on different files that showed up). I'mm using git push origin master since I'm on the master branch. I honestly don't know if this is a pure git problem since webpack isn't sensing these changes either...

Comment: What git status returns?

Comment: Might it be that locally you're modifying a different copy of the file than the one that is being tracked in your local GitHub repository?

Comment: just found discovered that this is the answer. I moved the file, but it was still open in my text editor, so when I saved it, saved it in the old location. So the file I'm referencing has remained unchanged. Dumb mistake!!

Comment: Thanks for all the help ladies and gents!

Answer (score 1):

Found the (dumb) answer. I moved the file, but it was still open in my text editor, so when I saved it, saved it in the old location. So the file I'm referencing has remained unchanged. Dumb mistake!